# Voting/Stars on Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.10

First time posting here, but I've recently started working in the Digital department in our company where we use Orchard as our CMS for the websites. I have been asked to look into rating of the content on the website so naturally I have been looking at Stars for Orchard but have had zero success so far.

Without any supplied documentation, I'm struggling to see where I am going wrong. I have downloaded the modules and installed them, I have enabled them, and I have selected Stars under Voting in Content Definition. The only option that I can see to add any sort of Voting is in the form of a widget, but without any supplied documentation for the module, I am struggling to get this working. Can anyone talk me through this? I am very new to Orchard, so if it is something simple then I apologise.

Comment: You've attached the stars part to your content type?

Comment: I enabled the Voting module, and Stars, and then selected Stars in Content Definition for Voting. It just seems to add Voting as a widget. When I add it into the page I just keep getting a 'There are no voted contents.' message. I think I'm struggling to link it to the specific content without having any documentation.

Comment: Is Voting your custom content type that you want to display stars on? For example, if you want people to be able to rate pages, attach the stars part the page content type, this should display the rating on each individual page. Check the error logs as well, just in case :) you shouldn't need the widget I don't think

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) the idea is that we have a page of Marketing resources for our clients. So we would like to add rating Stars next to each of these links so that our clients can rate the usefulness of the materials. Is this possible to do with Stars?

Comment: There used to be a gallery module called Contrib.Reviews. That had a ReviewsPart that would add the ability to leave a comment and a vote on an item. Is that what you are using here?